# Handle huge amount of items insertion/removal into RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I would like to ask the best way in your opinion to add and remove an huge amount of items into a recyclerview. Actually i can reach the score with 2 way:

- Adding removing the items one by one and call for each items:

  mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);

  mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(position);
- Adding removing the group of items and call after:

  mAdapter.notifyItemRangedInserted(start, end);

  mAdapter.notifyItemRangeRemoved(start, end);

These 2 way works pretty good, I can manage to add and remove my huge list of "pending" items but the UI will lag and freeze for a microsecond i guess due to the item appear/disappear animation.

Is there any good suggestion to manage a list of items that have to be added/removed at runtime? thank you!

**Edit:**

While i was asking the question i tought about creating 2 adapters. Could it be a better solution to swap the 2 adapter instead of managing a list of pending items? I think it will be faster but i'm gonna lose animations.

Comment: a microsecond is 1 / 1000000 sec, so its not an issue

Comment: let's say more then a microsecond :D. I need some other way!

Comment: disable animations then

Comment: let's also say that this is the "last way i wanna use". But if it will be necessary i'll disable animations. let's see if some ideas come out here!

Comment: btw did you try good old `public final void notifyDataSetChanged ()` ?

Comment: yes, sorry, forget to say! same result!